# pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for domainuser : 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)

Tags: ubuntu

pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user 503067775: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)

Im getting this error on ubuntun 16.04.
Local accounts ok to authenticate
Domain accounts not ok to authenticate.

We are using PAM SSSD to perform AD authentication.

Comment: facing same problem, did you manage to find any solution for this ?